# Xcode UI testing: How to know table reached end in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitest

Wanted to know the table is reached end or not using UI testing. Basically I have the requirement to find the button with in the tableview and the button will display some cases and wont for some cases. If the table reached end i will stop swiping up. Currently managing with some hard coded number of swipes.

Using hard coded number of swipes though the table content is less it will scrolls up. Is there any way to find the option to know table reached end or not.